# How to load timestamp properly to Amazon Redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a column which contains timestamp in format like this `2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.
But I cannot import the column to the table using
`full_date timestamp` in SQL create table command.

The error I got is `Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.`

But when I tried `timestamp("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` in W3School website, it worked.
But not in Amazon Redshift

Could you please help me? Or do I need to get the new format of timestamp?

Comment: You say that you "cannot import the column". Can you show us how you are attempting to 'import' the column? Is it via a COPY command? If so, can you show us the command and some sample data? What does the `stl_load_errors` table say for the failed import?

Comment: Yes. via COPY command